# Find the value of $\int_0^4g'(\sqrt x)dx$

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

> A function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^x \ln x+k \, &: \, (x \geq 1) \\
>  f(2-x) \, &: \, (x<1) \end{cases}$$ satisfies $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=5$. Let
>   $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$.
>
> Find the value of $\int_0^4g'(\sqrt x)dx$.

I've tried using integration by parts and fundamental theorem of R.I. but couldn't really make much of it. I couldn't find the way to avoid that $x^x$ part in the integral. Any help is appeciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $> f(2-x)$ in the second row of your piecewise definition?

Comment: @Sobi Quoting messed up with Latex. Sorry. Corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f$ is symmetric with respect to the vertical line $x=1$. Since $f$ is continuous, the FTC yields
$$ g'(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} f(t) \, dt = f(\sqrt{x})\cdot \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} = \frac{f(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}.  $$
Hence, by doing the substitution $x \mapsto \sqrt{x},$ and exploiting the symmetry of $f$, we get
$$ \int_0^4 g'(\sqrt{x}) \, dx = \int_0^4 \frac{f(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}\, dx = \int_0^2 f(x) \, dx = 2\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 10. $$